# “sEstimatedSize2” registry getting created in Uninstall\{ProductCode} hive

Tags: windows, installation, windows-registry

On Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4, multiple entries are getting created for cost estimation of MSI.

Under `HKLM..\Uninstall\{ProductCode}` `EstimatedSize` entry is created during MSI execution, but after some time I can see another entry getting automatically created `sEstimatedSize2`, the values indicated in this registry is same as that of `EstimatedSize`.

The issue is, during uninstall the `{ProductCode}` hive remains with that `sEstimatedSize2` registry.

Anybody have any idea why this is getting created?

Comment: It's a "Technical Preview" so anomalies should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10cb99f9-c751-4298-8e1f-af135d9aafba/sestimatedsize2-registry-getting-created-in-uninstallproductcode-hive?forum=windbg), the stack trace in Process Monitor shows that the "**sEstimatedSize2**" Registry value was created by **StorSvc.dll** during an incoming RPC. I don't think it is related to Windows Installer. StorSvc.dll implements the "Storage Service" service but I have not tested whether disabling this service would prevent the value from being created. Windows Installer doesn't delete the Registry value when uninstalling.